# GETTING ERROR when updating database in vb.NeT

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'M Creating A Database updater using vb.NET  and database AS DATABASE1.SDF. I I WANTED TO Update the DATABASE IN DATAGridview dynamically. For UPDATING SQL COMMAND  i'm USING A SQLCECOMMANDBUILDER BUT I'M GETTING A ERROR THERE AS "The DataAdapter.SelectCommand property needs to be initialized."
HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Public Class Admin
    Dim update As New SqlCeDataAdapter
    ' sql connection strings 
    Dim SQLCon As String = "Data Source=Database1.sdf"

    Dim sqlstr As String = "Select * from Base_Plate "
    Dim sqlstr1 As String = "Select * from Alloy "
    Dim sqlstr2 As String = "Select * from Bead_Factor "
    Dim sqlstr3 As String = "Select * from Difficulty_Factor "
    Dim sqlstr4 As String = "Select * from Price_Factor "

    ' sql variable of base
    Dim adapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlstr, SQLCon)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    ' sql variable of alloy
    Dim adapter1 As New SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlstr1, SQLCon)
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet()

    ' sql  variable of bead
    Dim adapter2 As New SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlstr2, SQLCon)
    Dim ds2 As New DataSet()

    'sql variable of difficulty
    Dim adapter3 As New SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlstr3, SQLCon)
    Dim ds3 As New DataSet()

    'sql variable of price
    Dim adapter4 As New SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlstr4, SQLCon)
    Dim ds4 As New DataSet()

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        update.Update(ds)
        LoadGrid()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Visible = False
        LoginForm1.Visible = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Admin_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LoadGrid()
        Button2.Enabled = False

    End Sub
    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
        Button2.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadGrid()


        '************** base datagrid ********************

        adapter.Fill(ds, "Base_Plate")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        DataGridView1.Rows(0).Selected = True

        '***************** alloy datagrid *********************

        adapter1.Fill(ds1, "Alloy")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds1.Tables(0)
        DataGridView2.Rows(0).Selected = True

        '***************** bead datagrid *********************

        adapter2.Fill(ds2, "Bead_Factor")
        DataGridView3.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)
        DataGridView3.Rows(0).Selected = True

        '***************** difficulty datagrid *********************

        adapter3.Fill(ds3, "Difficulty_Factor")
        DataGridView4.DataSource = ds3.Tables(0)
        DataGridView4.Rows(0).Selected = True

        '***************** Price datagrid *********************

        adapter4.Fill(ds4, "Price_Factor")
        DataGridView5.DataSource = ds4.Tables(0)
        DataGridView5.Rows(0).Selected = True

        update.UpdateCommand = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder(update).GetUpdateCommand
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please refrain from writing in ALL CAPS - first of all, it's annoyingly hard to read, and second it's considered **shouting** at your audience which is just plain rude and offensive.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.  Firstly, as the error message states, you haven't set the `SelectCommand` of the data adapter that you're passing to the command builder constructor.  Here's the relevant snippets from your code:

```
Dim update As New SqlCeDataAdapter

update.UpdateCommand = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder(update).GetUpdateCommand
```

As you can see, nowhere do you provide a SQL `SELECT` statement so how is the command builder supposed to know how to build the other commands?

Secondly, even if the adapter was properly configured, this is wrong:

```
update.UpdateCommand = New SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommandBuilder(update).GetUpdateCommand
```

You DO NOT have to get the commands from the command builder and assign them to the properties of the data adapter.  The only reason to do that is if you want to edit them, which you do not.  The proper way to create a command builder is on the line immediately after you create the data adapter, e.g.

```
Dim myDataAdapter As New SqlCeDataAdapter(query, myConnection)
Dim myCommandBuilder As New SqlCeCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter)
```

That's it.  You create it once and once only and then the data adapter will just work when you call `Update`.  There's no creating a new one each time you save and there's no getting and assigning of commands.

Comment: Thanx. I alread solved the problem. But thanx for your solution. Sorry for my caps, it's damaged.